# If X is a random variable, what is non X

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If X is a random variable 
$ X :    $$
    \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -6 & -3  \\ 1/4 & 2/4 & 1/4\end{bmatrix}$

How I can find $X^c$ ?

This is what I think is correct?

$ X^c :    $$
    \begin{bmatrix} -9 & -6 & -3  \\ 3/4 & 2/4 & 3/4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What does $X^c$ mean? How does the matrix given in the first line specify a random variable?

Comment: @littleO Alex is tabulating $P(X \neq x)$ for $x \in \{-9, -6, -3\}$.

Comment: This notation is way non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have been given a represention of the distribution for $X$ using a table of its support and corresponding probability mass.   That is okay, but should have been mentioned, or labeled, to avoid confusion.

$$\left[\begin{array}{r:rrr} x & -9 & -6 & -3 \\ \mathsf P(X=x) & 1/4 & 2/4 & 1/4\end{array}\right]$$

The table you produced matches the support for $X$ to the probability mass for its complement.   That appears to be what is required in as much as $X^c$ can be understood as the complement of random varible $X$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{r:rrr} x & -9 & -6 & -3 \\ \mathsf P(X\neq x) & 3/4 & 2/4 & 3/4\end{array}\right]$$

If it is a concern, you should not expect the probability masses of this table to sum to one, since the events are not disjoint.   $X^c$ is not itself a random variable.

Comment: Can you explain that last part? It's kinda confusing. Why shouldn't we expect it to be 1

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio It is because the events contain common outcomes: they are not disjuncts. ${\quad\mathsf P(X\neq -9)+\mathsf P(X\neq -6)+\mathsf P(X\neq -3)\\=\big(\mathsf P(X=-6)+\mathsf P(X=-3)\big)+\big(\mathsf P(X=-9)+\mathsf P(X=-3)\big)+\big(\mathsf P(X=-9)+\mathsf P(X=-6)\big)\\= 2}$

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought you meant adding to each member their counterpart in the other table (which adds up to 1 in all three cases). Yes, I can see why that happens